# How to include my virtual console ID in the prompt, in FreeBSD

Tags: bash, zsh, freebsd, prompt, virtual-consoles

When I use virtual consoles `ALT-F<1~n>` in FreeBSD, I want my 'zsh', 'sh' (and possibly other shells) startup scripts to include the virtual console number in the prompt, if it's not the default console '1'.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `PS1` conditionally on the value of `$TTY`. The first virtual console is `/dev/ttyv0`, the second one is `/dev/ttyv1`, etc.

For zsh, do it in `~/.zshrc`. For bash, do it in `~/.bashrc`.

```
if [[ $TTY == /dev/ttyv[1-9]* ]]; then
  PS1="[${TTY#/dev/ttyv}] $PS1"
fi
```

The code for doing just this is the same in bash and zsh. If you want further effects in your prompt (current directory, host name, colors, …), the format of `PS1` depends on the shell: [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Simple-Prompt-Escapes) and [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) both support prompt escapes, but they're completely different.

Answer (score 1):

KVTs are not the console, which is either serial, video, or mute.  The default kernel virtual terminal on FreeBSD is actually 0, its device file named `/dev/ttyv0`, not 1.  This is not Linux.  So I suggest that you have it in your prompt unconditially, at least until you are used to the actual numbering.  ☺

That's really easy in the Z shell.  I have it in my `RPROMPT`:

```
RPROMPT=%y
```

All shell variables for prompts should (of course) be set in the appropriate interactive shell rc file, such as `.zshrc`, and not exported.

If you want just the number, not the device name, it's simply a different percent sequence:

```
RPROMPT=%j
```

However, `%j` results in confusion if you also employ this in shells attached to GUI terminal emulators, or user-space virtual terminals, as the Z shell yields the same numbering for pseudo-terminals as for KVTs.

The FreeBSD Almquist shell does not have a prompt sequence for this that can be put into its `PS1` shell variable (and does not have right-hand-side prompts, either).  You asked for something that works with the FreeBSD Almquist shell also.  Gilles' answer does not, and neither do prompt metacharacter sequences.

There *is no* `TTY` environment variable set up in KVT login sessions (unless you use my nosh toolset, which *adds* this convention for terminal login on FreeBSD by dint of its `vc-get-tty` program).  Gilles' answer *only* works because the Z shell provides an implicit `TTY` shell variable.  It does not work for the FreeBSD Almquist shell or other shells that you might employ such as the Korn shell, where there is no implicit shell variable nor any environment variable.

For those, you will have to resort to first having something like:

```
export TTY="`tty`"
```